# Correct Python project structure for packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I am creating a Python utility that will need to be shared internally via `pip` packages, and will be consumed both as a library and as a command-line tool.

I am having difficulty with the correct use of namespaces and where/when/if to put `__init__.py` files to get a consistent codebase.

- I can get "library" usage working, so I can `from example_service.example import Example`.
- I can get CLI usage working, so I can execute `python example_service/example_cli.py`.
- I can get `pytest` working.
- I CANNOT get all three working at once.

So

- Should my package's use `from filename import Class` or `from .filename` or `from example_service.filename`?
- Should I put a `__init__.py` in my package directory or not? It seems it should not be necessary for Python3, but I get mixed results.

---

- If

  - `example.py` uses `from componenta import ComponentA` and
  - `example_cli.py` uses `from example import Example`
  - then the CLI invokation **works**
  - the library import **fails** with `no component named 'componenta'`
- If

  - `example.py` uses `from example_service.componenta import ComponentA` and
  - `example_cli.py` uses `from example import Example`
  - then the CLI invokation **fails** with `no component named 'example_service'`
  - the library import **works**

---

I currently have a project directory that looks something like this:

```
project_root/
    example_service/
        example.py
        example_cli.py
        componenta.py
        componentb.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_example.py
    setup.py
    requirements.txt
```

Inside my main lib code, `example.py`, I have:

```py
from componenta import ComponentA

class Example(object):
    def foo(self):
        a = ComponentA()
        print("Example.foo()")
```

My CLI wrapper will handle args and stuff, but for now is just:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from example import Example

class ExampleCli(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("ExampleCli.init()")
        e = Example()
        e.foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleCli()
```

And `componenta.py` is:

```py
class ComponentA(object):
    def bar(self):
      print("ComponentA.bar()")
```

(Full code has been posted to [GitHub](https://github.com/Cylindric/python_package/tree/zz_so1/))

Comment: Still having issues? I cloned your repository and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @sinoroc it was a silly environmental problem. I had just forgotten to `pip install -e .`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

- It's true that a package without `__init__.py` should work (since Python 3.3 I think). You can leave it out, if you don't need it (i.e.: you have nothing to write in it).
- I would not call `python example_service/example_cli.py` directly, ever. You have the *setuptools* *entry point* for this purpose, so in your case call `example` directly instead. (You can remove the shebang and the executable bit from `example_service/example_cli.py`.)
- from within your package `example_service` you can either use `from example_service.componenta import ComponentA` or `from .componenta import ComponentA`. This should work the same in both cases.